# Show that $|z+1| = 2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Show that $|z+1| = 2\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$, $z = cis(\theta)$ and $z \in C$

Here is what I have managed to do:

- $r=1$
- $(z+1)^2 = (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)+1)^2$
- $(z+1)^2 = (\cos^2(\theta)+2(i\sin(\theta)+1)\cos(\theta)+(i\sin(\theta)+1)^2)$
- $(z+1)^2 = (\cos^2(\theta)+2i\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\theta)+(-\sin^2(\theta)+2i\sin(\theta)+1))$

What I wanted to do was to take the square root of both sides to get the absolute value, however, I need to simplify the right-hand side first. I need help with that part

Comment: Note that $|z|$ is not $\sqrt{z^2}$ for complex $z$. For one thing, $|z|$ is a real number and $z^2$ is complex (and so $\sqrt{z^2}$ -- which is not well defined -- is in general also complex).

Comment: Hint: use that the angle at the circumference is half the angle at the centre

Comment: Hint: $\;|z+1|^2=(z+1)(\bar z+1)=|z|^2 + 1 + z + \bar z= 2 + 2\text{Re}(z)\,$.

Comment: @Snaw is it the same way that $(\sqrt{-1})(\sqrt{-1}) \not= -1$?

Comment: @ShootingStars In general we can't discuss $\sqrt{z}$ for $z$ a complex number because there are two such roots and a choice has to be made about which one we mean. For real numbers we decide that the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ represents the positive root, but for complex numbers that no longer works. This is not the real issue here though. The problem is that the formula $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ only works for real $x$. For complex numbers, $|z|$ is supposed to be real, but $\sqrt{z^2}$ is complex (even if we ignore the issue of which of the two values we mean).

Comment: So, then what does $\sqrt{z^2}$ to? Is it just $z$?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Given a point $z = a + bi$ in the complex plane, the magnitude of $z$ is $|z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, from the Pythagorean theorem. Plot the point $z + 1 = a + bi + 1 = [a + 1] + bi$ on the complex plane, and determine the magnitude $|z+1|$ from there. Replace $a = \cos\theta$ and $b = \sin\theta$.
2. Use the half-angle formula for cosine: $\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{2}}$.

Comment: I do not understand why the $1$ goes with the $\cos(\theta)$ and not the $\sin(\theta)$? Is it due to the vector "$1$" addition with the vector $z$?

Comment: @ShootingStars Write $z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$. Then what's $z+1$? Gather the real parts together

Comment: Take a point $z$ in the complex plane and add $1$ to it, where does it go? It shifts to the right one unit, because you're increasing the real part with that $1$. If instead, you had added $i$ to it, you'd shift up one unit because you're increasing the imaginary part by $1i$.

Answer (score 0):

note that
$z = \text{cis}(\theta)$ and $1 = \text{cis}(0)$,

you can rewrite the function as
$|\text{cis}(\theta)+\text{cis }(0)|$

use the identity that
$ \text{cis}(x+y) = \text{cis}(x) \ \text{cis}(y)$ with $\frac{\theta}{2}$ from $\theta$ and $0$